# For a given $A$, find a matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$, where

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}9 & 4 & -8 & 4\\4 & 9 & -4 & 8\\-8 &-4 & 9 & -4\\4 & 8 & -4 & 9\end{bmatrix}.$$

The matrix is symmetric and real, therefore is diagonizable with positive eigenvalues, so after the hard work of diagonizing the matrix the problem becomes trivial. My question is: there has to be an easier way to do it, but what is it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do you think there has to be an easier way?

Comment: It's just a hunch based on the fact that in class we weren't this technical in class and that there seems to be, in the very least an "easy" way to diagonalize this matrix.

Comment: Symmetric and real doesn't guarantee positive eigenvalues...

Comment: Make Wolfram Alpha diagonalize it for you!

Comment: Specifically, you can ask Wolfram Alpha this:diagonalize [[ 9, 4, -8, 4], [4, 9, -4, 8], [-8, -4, 9, -4], [4, 8, -4, 9]]  based on the output there may have been a clever way (the evects have only plus minus 1s and 0s as entries) but I don't see it.

Comment: I like the spelling-error *"di-agonizing"* which focuses on the *agonizing* work when eigensystem-decomposition of large matrices is required. Therefore: no spell-correction this time ... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that $(1,1,-1,1)$ is an eigenector with eigenvalue 25.
With a bit more work, $(1,0,1,0)$ and $(0,1,0,-1)$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1.

The last one is harder to guess, but remember that it is a real symmetric matrix can diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix, which means that the last eigenvector is orthogonal to the 3 that we found. Hence, it is $(1, -1,-1, -1)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Newton's square-root-finder applied to matrices:

$ \qquad \qquad  \displaystyle B = I \\ 
\qquad \qquad  B = (A \cdot B^{-1} + B) / 2 \qquad \qquad \text{ iterate to convergence }$

Trying it myself : after 7 iteration I've approximation to half-integers with so many digits precision that I have confidence to the rounded result:
$$
 B = \frac 12 \cdot \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 5 & 1 & -3 & 1 \\ 
 1 & 5 & -1 & 3 \\ 
 -3 & -1 & 5 & -1 \\ 
 1 & 3 & -1 & 5
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Indeed, the final test $ B ^2 - A = 0$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

Another -simpler- way, but which is still employing the concept of diagonalization *(which seems to be what you wish according to your comment at the question-box)* is using SVD-decomposition. Since A is symmetric the SVD and the diagonalization coincide. SVD (and in this case diagonalization too) can be obtained by column/row-rotations only which might be seen as simpler.